# Find the direct complement of $U$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Hi everyone ! Can someone please help me with the task? I already did A and B part from where i got that:
A) Proved that $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$ are lineraly independent (by considering the equation a $\cos(2x) + b \sin(x) + c \sin x^2$);
B) Got basis $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(x)^2$.
But i have some problems with the C part: I tried to extened, I know how to do it with numbers but I have no idea how am I suppose to do it with $\sin$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What inner product are you using?

Comment: @MatthewH. What do you mean by inner product ?

Comment: My apologies, I interpreted direct complement as *orthogonal* complement. To be clear, you're trying to find a subspace $\mathbb{V}$ such that $\mathbb{U}\cap \mathbb{V}=\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{U}+\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{W}$, correct?

Comment: @MatthewH. yup, exactly!

Comment: Why not just take $\mathbb{V}=\text{span}\{\cos(2x)\}$?

Comment: @MatthewH. can you please explain why V = span{cos(2x)} is a valid option?

Comment: $\mathbb{V}=\text{span}\{\cos(2x)+\sin(x)\}$ is also a valid option, which makes me wonder why they're referring to the direct complement in a singular way. Anyway, you just have to show that $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{U}+\mathbb{V}$ and that $\mathbb{U}\cap \mathbb{V}=\{0\}$. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @MatthewH. Can you please explain how exactly i can show that W = U + V with sin ( I ve been stuck with it for hours...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\mathbb{W}$ has a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and $\mathbb{U} \subset \mathbb{W}$ is the span of $v_1, \dots, v_k$ for some $k \le n$ then the span of $v_{k + 1}, \dots, v_n$ is a direct complement of $\mathbb{U}$ in $\mathbb{W}$. This follows directly from the definition of a basis.